# Dereferencing the first and last entry of std::vector

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Using Vstudio build in Release mode, the construct `&a[0]` when `a.size()==0` and `std::vector<type>(&a[i], &a[i+1])` when `i+1==a.size()` are totally fine and is optimized away by the compiler. But it is not accepted in Debug build. Is there a flag to tell the compiler to accept it?

Comment: I removed the tag [visual-build-professional] since this was not mentioned in the question and does not seem relevant

Answer (score 0):

"totally fine" is a synonym for undefined behavior. That the bad instructions were optimized away is, perhaps, lucky.

The debug build is showing you a problem.

Comment: But why gcc allows this also in Debug build is mysterious to me :(

Comment: That's why I asked. Maybe gcc has a flag to allow/not allow this behaviour.

Comment: Some static analysis or extra checks in debug mode might find this. There is no flag to remove instructions that walk out of bounds.